# Windows 7 all icons dissapeared from desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

I've got a vaio laptop that was working fine till yesterday ( the only problem is that the screen is broken so i always attach it to a monitor with hdmi) but when i opened it today only the wallpaper is shown on desktop(no icons). I tried to system restore writing on cmd rstrui.exe but i can only see the wimdows in minimized form by leaving the mouse on system restore icon. I tried to complete system restore by just hitting enter but i can't complete it like this (since i can see it only in minimised i can't navigate using the mouse). Most answers i found where proposing to use task manager but i can only see task manager in minimised form. Any idea will be really helpfull. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you still see the taskbar?

Comment: Does it work as expected/better in Safe Mode? Why not boot from your Windows DVD (or a repair disk) and run a Repair/System Restore from there?

Comment: Set the external monitor as the primary monitor instead of the secondary monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your windows are appearing on your broken laptop screen and thats why everything appears only on minimized form.

You can still move the windows to your normal screen using the following trick.

## Method one

Make sure the application is selected, then use the following keys <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> repeat a few times untill the application shows on your screen.

If this doesn't work, (it can happen if the application is opened as minimised, do the following):

## Method two

- On the task Make sure the program is highlighted, then hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and right click the application.
- Select `move`
- press any <kbd>arrow key</kbd> (this will snap the window to your mousecursor)
- Move your mouse around. The window should move into your sight.
- Click once to release the window.
- If the window appears to be one small bar, increase its size by dragging the bottom right edge away from the window.

## Fixing the issue

Using either Method one or Method two, you can fix the issue by doing the following:

- Rightclick on your deskop and choose Screen Resolution
- Select your secondary screen
- Make sure this is set to your default monitor by checking [v] Make this my main display and hitting apply.

If after opening of the screen resolution, that window appears on your other screen, use method one or two to get the screen onto your current display.

Answer (score 0):

Show desktop icons is unselected. To Fix this just turn that option back on. To turn the option back on , Follow the steps:

1. Right click the desktop.
2. Select View and then Show desktop icons.
3. Make sure the option is checked.